# Android reyclerview does not get updated after restoring room database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-mvvm

In restore screen, I restore my sqlite db (room database) file from google drive.
After I go back to my main activity - the recyclerview shows the cached data instead of showing new restored db data.

I tried initialising my ViewModel again in main activity - but that did not help.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setupViewModel(); // re-initialising my ViewModel
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your expenses have been restored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

If I restart my app after restore, I can see data from restored db on main activity.

Any help would be appreciated.
Workaround that I have now is - I can ask user to restart the app after they restore db from google drive.

updates:

```
private void setupViewModel() {
        //Associate ViewModel to this activity
        ItemViewModel itemViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemViewModel.class);
        itemViewModel.getItems().observe(this, new Observer<List<Item>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Item> items) {
                ItemsActivity.this.items = items;
                itemsAdaptor.setItems(items);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you close the database before restoring the backup? Did you re-open the database after restoring the backup? Are you doing something that is re-querying the database? Are you doing something that gets those query results out to your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yes, I updated the code for setupViewModel which calls getItems to query all data from database. Here issue is that, getItems gets called only if there are change in item list. Replacing the db file is not calling onChanged method.

Comment: Did you close the database before restoring the backup? Did you re-open the database after restoring the backup? Are you doing something that is re-querying the database? Because, from your code there, you appear to be doing none of those things. Close the database before restoring it. Re-open the database after restoring it. That will force you to re-query the database, as you now have a new `RoomDatabase` object and new DAO objects.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Yes, I closed existing database (also checked if db.isOpen() first) and called my room repository to open database again. But here the problem is list of items are stored in cache (as per MVVM design with Room database) and that list is not getting updated even re-query is happening. Thanks for your help. I was thinking if there exists any method other than closing/re-opening database in Room database to reflect the replaced db data.

Comment: "But here the problem is list of items are stored in cache" -- Room is not doing that. You are doing that. So, you need to re-query the database and update your cache after restoring the database. "that list is not getting updated even re-query is happening" -- then there is a bug in your caching code, I guess. "I was thinking if there exists any method other than closing/re-opening database in Room database to reflect the replaced db data" -- closing and reopening the database is necessary, regardless of the cache. Never have open handles to a file that you replace with a different file.

Comment: have you tried adding notifyDataSetChanged() after updating your data in adapter?

Comment: yeah already tried that and it did not work - @ritesh4302

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the app is solving issue for my usecase.

I am using following code to restart the app:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
finish();
startActivity(i);
System.exit(0);
```

Closing and re-opening the db should ideally work but is not working for me. Once the app is re-started, it is using the new restored db.